# Is it possible to get size of retained heap memory by a given Thread without creating memory dump programatically?

Tags: java, performance, memory, memory-management, monitoring

Is it possible to get size of retained heap memory by a given Thread without creating memory dump programatically?

I know that it's possible to get the size of memory in runtime context like:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

but i need to calculate memory occupied by given Thread without creating memory dump.

**UPDATE:**  A Thread allocates object while execution. At any given moment JVM knows which objects has been allocated by which Thread. So I need to extract size of memory for objects that have been allocated by given Thread.

Is it possible?

Comment: use a profiling tool

Comment: I need to do it programatically. Maybe with instrumenting the code.

Comment: Thread A creates an object O, and hands it to thread B.  How would you define which thread owns object O?

Comment: .... you might usefully collect information about how much data a thread has allocated via new(...).  What will you do with the answer?

Comment: I thought about instrumentation of new (here I have ability to get current Thread ID - thread that created the object). Maybe i can also instrument finalise() methods (but how to get Thread ID which created an object??? Finalise is called by GC). Also i need to calculate memory for each threads on new and on finalise. I have concerns about overhead in such case. May be the better decision exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem---threads do not have memory. A process has memory. A thread is just one execution stream within the process. The only memory assigned dedicated to a thread is the stack (even that is usually process managed).

There is then no heap memory retained by a thread.

Comment: May be i didn't explain well. A Thread allocates object while execution. At any given moment JVM knows which objects has been allocated by which Thread. So I need to extract size of memory for objects that have been allocated by given Thread. It's possible to do with memory dump. But i need more efficient way. May be with instrumentation.